# Duplicating configuration of the settings for apps and tabs in another team

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a configuration issues within Microsoft team.
In our company, we have several projects that follows the same steps to complete. In order to be more efficient, I thought of creating different teams based on those different projects with the appropriate team members (not always the same from one team to another).

I was then trying to create one standard team where I would define all the tabs and app required. I would also for instance upload the lists needed, the tasks required along the way, link the team to the common Sharepoint and so on.
However, when creating a new team from this team I noticed you have to configure again all the tabs and apps of your new created team.
It will make me gain a considerable amount of time if the configuration could be "duplicated" from one team to another one.
I have thought of create one single team and creating different channel (which would represent my new team) but this will be a bit messy and the team members are not always the same.

Is there anyway the configuration within the tabs and apps of one team could be duplicated to a new one?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot duplicate an existing team. Currently this is by design. You can upvote the [feature request](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/35608516-duplicate-clone-a-channel-within-a-team) to make this feature available in future.